# Adding Thorlabs DCC cmos as an input device in Matlab to record video?

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to record timing video from a Thorlabs DCC cmos 1280x1024 with a code in Matlab but Matlab don't recognize it as a video device in `imaqhwinfo,
a=imaqhwinfo('winvideo',1)` command.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported hardware, see the [Supported Hardware](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/hardware-support/index.html?q=product%3A%22Image%20Acquisition%20Toolbox%22) page.

Your options are to either [request](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/hardware-support/request-hardware-support.html) for your hardware to be added to the supported hardware list (if you're prepared to wait a few years...) or use the [adaptor kit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/pdf_doc/imaq/adaptorkit.pdf) to write a communication layer between the Image Acquisition Toolbox acquisition engine and the third-party SDK and drivers for your hardware. However, this is a very advanced manoeuvre for experienced users and requires extensive knowledge of the hardware vendor's SDK (and is not something I can help you with).